# JanusGraph: Some key(s) on index byAllTweetFields do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]

Tags: janusgraph

I have many data on JanusGraph DB and I created an index. But when index created no data indexed.

The line of code which prints the log is this:

```
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(jGraph, index.name).timeout(10, ChronoUnit.DAYS).call()
```

The log is:

```
GraphIndexStatusWatcher - Some key(s) on index byAllTweetFields do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: idCode=INSTALLED,text=INSTALLED,title=INSTALLED,urgencyLevel=INSTALLED
```

I used Cassandra and ElasticSearch as backend DBs.

What I have missed?